# Pretrained retinanet model with Keras. SavedModel file does not exist at: "path"/"file".h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, retinanet

I'm trying to load a pretrained retinanet model with keras by running:

```
# import keras
import keras

# import keras_retinanet
from keras_retinanet import models
from keras_retinanet.utils.image import read_image_bgr, preprocess_image, resize_image
from keras_retinanet.utils.visualization import draw_box, draw_caption
from keras_retinanet.utils.colors import label_color


# set tf backend to allow memory to grow, instead of claiming everything
import tensorflow as tf

def get_session():
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    return tf.Session(config=config)
model_path = os.path.join('sample_data/snapshots', sorted(os.listdir('sample_data/snapshots'), reverse=True)[0])
print(model_path)


# load retinanet model
model = models.load_model(model_path, backbone_name='resnet50')

model = models.convert_model(model)
```

I am facing the following error with both codes:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: sample_data/snapshots/training_5000(640_480).h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

the cause might be some new versions of Keras or tensorflow,
soo I am going to list the versions that I am currently using.

```
keras.__version__
2.4.3

tf.__version__
2.4.1
```

Note: I am trying to run this code in my Colab.

Comment: I think you need to use the corresponding loading function from keras_retinanet: `from keras_retinanet.models import load_model`

Comment: yes you are right, but still didn't work. Let me update the question

Comment: But the error is now another one, right? Have you checked if the folder/files from the error message exist on your system?

Comment: Yes the file exist and I can enter the directory and download the .h5 file, from colab dive into my own computer.

Comment: I solved the problem by using the same code in ubuntu virtual machine.
maybe later I'll post an answer, and add some links, because I noticed many facing the same problem, on GitHub forms

Comment: Okay, I see, so it might be an issue of the OS path formatting?

Comment: I really don't know, I gave up trying to solve the problem in Colab, because it takes for ever to upload pretrained model to the drive.

Comment: I see. Strange though, as the given path formatting shouldn't be an issue on Colab. Maybe the working directory was not correctly set ... but nevermind, given that you found another solution.

Comment: Google colab file structure looks like`/content/`. Check the file path. Thanks!